# Outlook 2013 install with Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have office 2010 without Outlook on my Windows 7 computer. Can I install Outlook 2013 without damaging the Office 2010 programs (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, etc)?

Comment: Why not upgrade the whole Office suite?

Answer (score 0):

You can. To install Outlook 2013 side-by-side with Outlook 2010 you'll need click-to-run package (install from Office 365 site). To install Outlook 2013 side-by-site with Office 2010 you can use DVD/ISO (MSI) installer but Outlook 2010 will be removed during the installation in this case.